# How to check last three elements from a python list - whether they are integer?

Tags: python

I am using Python, version 2.7.2.

I have a task to check whether the last three elements from a list are integer?
For example:

```
mylist = [String, Large_string_containing_integers_inside_it, 80, 40, 50]
```

For above list I want to check whether the last three elements are integer or not.
How can I do this?

Here is the code I am testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

line = ['MKS_TEST', 'Build', 'stability:', '1', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'last', '2', 'builds', 'failed.', '80', '40', '50']

if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in line[-3:]):
    job_name = line[0]
    warn = line[-3]
    crit = line[-2]
    score = line[-1]
    if score < crit:
        print ("CRITICAL - Health Score is %d" % score)
    elif (score >= crit) and (score <= warn):
        print ("WARNING - Health Score is %d" % score)
    else:
        print ("OK - Health Score is %d" % score)
```

Comment: The last three elements aren't integers, they're strings. The `if` block will never execute.

Comment: actully the list `line` is an output of another script.
The other script just prints  this `MKS_TEST Build stability: 1 out of the last 2 builds failed. 80 40 50` on console.
According to this output I am doing the code testing shown in the question

Comment: I have edited my answer to allow for that.

Answer (score 7):

Use the built in `isinstance` and `all` functions, along with list slicing.

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in mylist[-3:]):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

- `all` checks if all elements in the given iterable evaluate to `True`.
- `isinstance` checks if the given object is an instance of the second parameter
- `mylist[-3:]` returns the last three elements of `mylist`

Also, if you're using Python 2 and have very large numbers in your list, check for the `long` (long integer) type as well.

```
if all(isinstance(i, (int, long)) for i in mylist[-3:]):
    pass
```

This prevents numbers like `10**100` from breaking the condition.

If, however, your last three elements are strings, you have two options.

If you know none of the numbers are exceedingly large, you can use the `isdigit` string method.

```
if all(i.isdigit() for i in mylist[-3:]):
    pass
```

However, if they can be very large (around or over `2**31`), use a `try/except` block and the built in `map` function.

```
try:
    mylist[-3:] = map(int, mylist[-3:])
    # do stuff
except ValueError:
    pass
```

- `try` defines the block of code to execute
- `except Exception` catches the given exception and handles it without raising an error (unless told to do so)
- `map` applies a function to each element of an iterable and returns the result.

Comment: missing `int` in the `isisntance` call

Comment: @root Yeah, forgot to put that in

Comment: Should be `isinstance(i, (int, long))`

Comment: int and long for 2.x, isinstance( i, ( int, long ) )

Comment: ` #!/usr/bin/python

    
    line = ['MKS_TEST', 'Build', 'stability:', '1', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'last', '2', 'builds', 'failed.', '80', '40', '50']
    
    if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in line[-3:]):
     job_name = line[0]
     warn = line[-3]
     crit = line[-2]
     score = line[-1]
     if score < crit:
      print ("CRITICAL - Health Score is %d" % score)
     elif (score >= crit) and (score <= warn):
      print ("WARNING - Health Score is %d" % score)
     else:
      print ("OK - Health Score is %d" % score)
`
Thanks!!
I am using above code. Nothing get printed on console.

Comment: @user2010736 please don't post large blocks of code in comments, edit your question instead. It's unreadable in it's current state.

Comment: The comment I just added doesn't seem to be understandable.
I ll add it to the answer.